# How to retrieve a total pixel value above an average-based threshold in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, pixel, threshold

Currently, I am practicing with retrieving the total of the pixel values above a threshold based on the mean of the whole image. (I am very new to Python). I am using Python 3.5.2, and the above code was copied from the Atom program I am using to write and experiment with the code.

For the time being, I am just practicing with the red channel - but eventually, I will need to individually analyse all colour channels.

The complete code that I am using so far:

```
import os  
from skimage import io  
from tkinter import *  
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename  
def callback():  
    M = askopenfilename()       #to select a file  
    image = io.imread(M)        #to read the selected file  
    red = image[:,:,0]          #selecting the red channel  
    red_av = red.mean()         #average pixel value of the red channel  
    threshold = red_av + 100    #setting the threshold value  
    red_val = red > threshold  
    red_sum = sum(red_val)  
    print(red_sum)  
Button(text = 'Select Image', command = callback).pack(fill = X)  
mainloop()
```

Now, everything works so far, except when I run the program, `red_sum` comes out to be the number of pixels above the `threshold`, not the total of the pixels.

What I am I missing? I am thinking that my (possible naive) way of declaring the `red_val` variable has something to do with it.

But, how do I retrieve the total pixel value above the threshold?

Comment: Not entirely sure why, but when I write it as above - I get a list of values for `red_sum` - but if I change the sum line (directly above) to `red_sum = red_val.sum()` I get a numerical answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you did `(red > threshold)` you got a mask such that all the pixels in red that are above the threshold got the value `1` and `0` otherwise. Now to get the values, you can just multiply the mask with the red channel. The multiplication will zero all the values that are less than the threshold and will leave the values over the threshold unchanged.

The code:

```
red_val = (red > threshold)*red
red_sum = sum(red_val)
```

Comment: Perfect! Your explanation makes perfect sense too - a very nice simple method that works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Another method I found that worked (providing the total pixel value) was to use masked values:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
...    

red_val = ma.masked_outside(red, threshold, 255).sum()
```

From the [SciPy.org documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_outside.html#numpy.ma.masked_outside) about masking, what this does is:

> Mask an array outside a given interval.

In the example, anything outside of the interval of the `threshold` (defined in my question) and `255` is 'masked' and does not feature in calculating the sum of pixel values.